# wp_logout action hook is not firing

Tags: php, wp-query, functions

Why the user meta value is not being changed after logout using the following code:

```
function update_login_status_on_logout() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'login_status', 'logged_out');
    }
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'update_login_status_on_logout');
```

Comment: Be aware that what you're trying to do won't work. Users can be logged in on one browser, and log out in another browser and your code will say that they are logged out, even though they're still logged in in first browser. Additionally, user sessions can expire, meaning that they are logged out, but there's no hook or code that runs when this happens, so your code will say that they are logged in when they're not.

Comment: So in that case what code can be used to show a status in the frontend by determining if a author of a post is online or offline in WordPress?

Comment: You should post that as its own question.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `get_current_user_id()` will return `0` because this hook fires *after* the logout has happened, ie, there is no current user ID.

If you want the `$user_id` to be available to your function, you have to pass it in. **Note:** the `$user_id` parameter was added in WordPress 5.5.0. If you're using an older version, this won't work the way you want.

```
function update_login_status_on_logout( $user_id ) {
    if ($user_id) {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'login_status', 'logged_out');
    }
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'update_login_status_on_logout');
```

### References

- [`wp_logout` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_logout/)
- [`wp_logout()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout/)